# Program that can download YouTube playlists?

Tags: windows, gratis, video, download-manager, youtube

Today I am looking for some kind of program that can download all videos from a YouTube playlist.

Some requirements I need are:

1. **It is free! / Not a trial.**
2. **Runs on Windows 8.1.** (Also acceptable: Either a Firefox or Chrome extension.)
3. **Downloads videos in playlist in order.**
4. **No adware / ads!**

Nice to haves are that it supports custom proxy configuration within application with authentication. On a side note it must be easy to use.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think omgeeky has an article (https://omgeeky.com/best-youtube-playlist-downloader/) which will help you to download Youtube Playlists.

Comment: found that on Kures.co - this is much faster for downloading.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/). It is command line tool. I tried this at only on Windows7. There is a GUI wrapper available called [win-youtube-dl](https://github.com/fredyw/win-youtube-dl) but it only works at 64-bit Windows.

- Open  source
- Supports a lot of video sharing sites
- Can download subtitle of video
- Free
- Multiplatform
- Supports authentication
- Works with proxy (I never tried this)
- Can download playlists and channels

Comment: Nice find. Being a command line tool means that you could run it in batch over a list of links. It's also the only answer with a software that does not come with bundled adware in the setup. Could you please edit the answer and elaborate more using the same features the OP requested? Reading [this post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/6834) might help on how to format your answer

Answer (score 5):

You can use [DVDVideoSoft's Free YouTube Download](http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/products/dvd/Free-YouTube-Download.htm):

- freeware
- ads-free (make sure you uncheck/skip the spyware when installing)
- standalone
- works with Windows
- can download YouTube playlists (largest playlists size tried: 182 videos)

[image]

[image]

[image]

It seems to work fine with non-ASCII characters, [example](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLCC67A0CADDE19926):

[image]

Make sure you uncheck/skip the spyware when installing:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Options:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems that as of version 4.1.29.1027, you need premium to be able to download playlists.

Comment: That doesn't look ad-free, but that looks manageable.

Comment: Some of the features have changed over time too.  For example, you can't append upload date any longer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/):

- freeware
- ads-free (make sure you uncheck/skip the spyware when installing JDownloader)
- standalone
- works with Windows/Linux/Mac
- can download YouTube playlists [if it contains fewer than 80 videos](https://superuser.com/q/743476/116475)
- tons of other features like custom proxy configuration within application with authentication.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wish it worked but none of them actually did. :(

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Both of them. I even got the cracked version of YTD video downloader and it didn't work and jdownloader, I was just trying to download a playlist and wouldn't work.

Comment: @Izumi-reiLuLu - can you clarify exactly what "wouldn't work" means? does the program launch? does it copy the URL? does it load the vidoes in the playlist? does it download them? and this answer is only for JDownloader, if you have issues on the YTD, perhaps comment on that answer instead?

Comment: For a program to make downloading easy, their website doesn't explain anything, and I can't get it to spit out a file.  Probably a temporary glitch, but still pretty embarrassing.

Answer (score 2):

[YTD Video Downloader](http://www.ytddownloader.com/) fits your criteria:

1. It is free*
2. Runs on Windows 8.1
3. Downloads entire playlist in order (see screenshots). **Edit** - The maximum playlist size appears to be 100 videos (see comments)
4. The setup is bundled with adware (Yahoo toolbar), but you can uncheck them using the custom installation settings

*It also has a paid version that offers simultanuous downloading and converting

[image]

When you paste the link of a video that's part of a playlist (ends with &list=XXXXX), YTD automatically offers to download the entire playlist

[image]

Make sure you uncheck the crapware during the installation:

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Can YTD Video Downloader download YouTube playlists having mover than 100 videos?](http://superuser.com/q/835141/116475)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Apparently not, and I haven't found any statement that says whether or not the full version supports larger playlists. One could either split the playlist in two (maximum YouTube playlist length is 200 videos, so only 2 sub-lists are needed), or use the alternative in your answer

Comment: I had the same issue with JDownloader, a non-documented limitation on the maximum size of a playlist it can handle...

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer:

You can use [ByTubeD](http://msram.github.io/bytubed/dev-versions/1.1.2a2.xpi) plugin with Mozilla Firefox and IDM.

Long Answer:

- Install above mentioned addon in your Firefox.
- Go to the Youtube playlist and right-click on its title.
- Select ByTubeD option.
- Your videos will take a while to get parsed into a list.
- Select the videos you want to download.
- Select resolution and video format.
- Select destination where the html page with parsed links will get saved.
- Open the saved html page(if not opened already) and right click on any link.
- Select 'Download All Links With IDM'.
- Voila! Now all you need to do is to go to your IDM and open its Scheduler, then go to second tab and remove all the old files which are on the top of your IDM's queue.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/743476/can-jdownloader-download-youtube-playlists-having-mover-than-80-videos/865675#865675

Answer (score 0):

Look at the wikipedia comparison oа downloaders:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_download_managers

Free YouTube Downloader and 4kDownloader can download the playlists and channels. 
Look up the guide https://www.dvdvideosoft.com/guides/how-to-download-youtube-playlist.htm

You need to copy the link to all the channel and SELECT the videos, or you will download all the channel of 100500 videos. If you need exactly that - dont choose)